# Confirmation dialog in a portlet

Tags: java, jsp, portlet

I am trying to implement a confirmation dialog in a Liferay portlet which shall be shown when user clicks on a link triggering **actionRequest**.

However, it seems that the portlet container does not have GUI, so I am getting `java.awt.HeadlessException`

This is the part relevant to my **JSP** page:

```
<li><a href="<%=deleteDatabase%>">Delete messages from database</a></li>

<portlet:actionURL var="deleteDatabase" name="deleteDatabase">
    </portlet:actionURL>
```

**Java** portlet class:

```
public void deleteDatabase(final ActionRequest actionRequest,
            final ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException,
            PortletException {

        int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                "Would You Like to delete all messages?", "Warning",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            // do some stuff here
        }

    }
```

Perhaps I shoulw not try to implement the dialog inside java but move it to the JSP and use javascript or I should do it some other way... Could be please give me a hint how to solve this exception in Java or show me an example code that would work with the actionURL? Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your imports.

You are using [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) from Swing.

You can run Swing as local applications. However the portlet is running on a server and therefor cannot render a local application to your clients over the WebBrowser.

You could check out Javascript libraries like [jQuery](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) which offer some dialog functions. These will be executed by the users browsers.